# Facebook connect with android sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth, facebook-android-sdk

I try to use the facebook authentification in my app but I'm not able to login, I'm always redirected to the form which ask me if I allow the app to access to my information (ie the "dologin" method in my code..
Here is my code:

```
package com.fbconnect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;
import com.facebook.widget.*;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;
    private Button buttonLoginLogout;

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        buttonLoginLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

        updateView();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Log.i("session log", session.toString());
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            welcome.setText("Hello !");
        } else {

            doLogin();
        }
    }

    private void doLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateView();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually came from the key hash
I had several stupid problems on windows, here are some advices:

- Dont use the windows cmd, do it through cygwin
- Dont use %HOMEPATH% (even if it's indicated on facebook...), prefer the long way: "C:\Users\...\.android\debug.keystore"
- Surround your keystore path with quotes (even if there is no spaces in it)
- If the generator doesn't ask you a password it won't work, you did something wrong in the command